Can bash warn about usage of a variable?
I'm dealing with a large collection of bash scripts, and need to eliminate the use of a variable which no longer makes sense.
The variable used to denote a path, and we're currently setting it to /var/empty. Is there a way to declare it in such a fashion that any references to it would cause bash to print a warning but not fail with an error? Sort of like the __attribute__ ((deprecated)) feature of the modern C/C++ compilers.
(Many of our scripts already begin with set -eu.)

AFAIK there's nothing like this in bash. Why not just search for it in an editor?

@Barmar, the scripts are many (hundreds). The scripts are spread across a dozen+ different git-repositories. Many of them aren't even used any more, but tracing, which of them can be deleted, is a hairy task of its own. It is messy and I thought, there might be a feature in bash, that'll make it easier for me to sort out...

I feel for you, my company also has enormous technical debt. Unfortunately, I think you're SOL.

scanning the source code seems the reliable way.  running a script doesn't guarantee a relevant code path is taken: one could run it 99 times without the variable being used but then the hundredth time it does get used.

What @jhnc said! Also regarding "Many of our scripts already begin with set -eu" - most people who've been programming in bash for a while would advise against using set -e and instead handling errors appropriately when they occur, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105.

@EdMorton, unexpected errors ought to be fatal -- like exceptions in programs written in other languages. To test exit code after every command is to double the script-size... The expected errors can be handled explicitly.

@MikhailT. I understand the theory, hopefully you've read through the FAQ to understand the issues around the reality of the implementation (which the FAQ summarizes with "These rules are extremely convoluted, and they still fail to catch even some remarkably simple cases. Even worse, the rules change from one Bash version to another, as Bash attempts to track the extremely slippery POSIX definition of this "feature". When a SubShell is involved, it gets worse still -- the behavior changes depending on whether Bash is invoked in POSIX mode") and if you're happy with that then go for it

Since you already have set -u in effect for many scripts, I would proceed as this: Say the name of your obsolete variable is obs. I would then define this variable with
typeset -rn obs=foobarbaz
typeset -n foobarbaz=obs

The -r produces an error message (readonly variable), if someone tries to set the variable obs to a new value.
If someone tries to read the variable obs, this would produce a warning *(circular name reference)*.
If set -u is in effect, reading the variable would in addition produce an error message (unbound variable) and abort the script.
